# using page.js with sinatra (or rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sinatra, page.js

I would like to know if it's possible to use [page.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js) with sinatra. My `images`'s route are intercepted by Sinatra instead of Page.js

```
get '/' do
  erb :index
end

__END__

@@ layout
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <title>page.js</title>
   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="page.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css">ul li { display: inline; list-style:none }</style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <%= yield %>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
page('/images', function(ctx){
      console.log('page(' + ctx.path + ')');
          $('section#example').html('<h2 class="text-center">Listing of Images</h2>');
});
/*... /videos ..*/
page('*', function(ctx){
      console.log('page(' + ctx.path + ')');
          $('section#example').html('<h2 class="text-center">Error : ' + ctx.path + '</h2>');
});

$('document').ready(function(){page()});

</script>
</html>

@@ index
    <ul>
      <li><a href="./">index</a></li>
      <li><a href="./videos">videos</a></li>
      <li><a href="./images">images</a></li>
    </ul>
   <section id="example" class="well"></section>
   <h1>hello world</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is just the location of your local `page.js` file. Sinatra expects to find the static assets in a directory called `public` (otherwise the path is assumed to be a defined route). So just create the directory and move your `page.js` file in there (but keep the script src as is). If you want to change the directory Sinatra serves static assets from, you can do it like this:

```
set :public_folder, Proc.new { File.join(root, "my_directory_with_assets") }
```

I think you're also missing `jQuery` so add it from their CDN.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Jiří! I didn't add Jquery that was the error :(

Comment: @PapoucheGuinslyzinho No problem, I'm glad you got that to work. Please accepts the answer so I can get the internet points :). Thanks!